# How to fix sed regex, whitespace or EOL?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to output and isolate between two strings or if it's at the end of the line. I seem to be struggling with the associated regex, I've tried a number of different combinations.

Example with trailing space: `echo "example --test=here stuff here" | sed -e 's/.*--test=\(.*\)[[:space:]]/\1/'`

Example with trailing EOL: `echo "example stuff here --test=here" | sed -e 's/.*--test=\(.*\)[[:space:]]/\1/'`

- The output of the trailing space is `here stuffhere`
- The output of the trailing EOL is `example stuff here --test=here`

The expected output is `here` (the following text after --test=), the goal is to output the text following the --test=*. Nothing else regardless if it's followed by a space or if it's end of the string.

Comment: Can you let us know what output you would like to have? Also, I don't see the trailing EOL in your second example.

Comment: For what it's worth, your pattern searches for and matches one space character after `test=`, which is why it got to just before the second `here` in the first example, and found nothing in the second one, since there is not space after `test=`.

Comment: It's really unclear what your actual question is. Are you trying to figure out a `sed` script which will do what you want (which is what?) in both cases?

Comment: Sorry, a bit of the post seemed to have cut off when I was typing this up. Fixed the post, but yeah trying to get the following: `here` from the first here in the following: `example --test=here stuff here`. Basically ONLY getting what is trailing --test=*. Not including anything the following wether it be a space or whitespace.

Comment: This website is very helpful for debug and understanding  https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks @pioupiou, I definitely need to upskill on regex! Long overdue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*--test=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

or

```
sed 's/.*test=//;s/ .*//'
```

Comment: Output as expected! I'd rather not admit how much time I spent trying this :P.

Thanks @Beta!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*--test=\(\S\+\)\s*.*/\1/p' file
```

Turn off automatic printing, and only print on successful substitution. Use `\s` and it's dual `\S` for whitespace and non-whitespace.

If it's the last word to be extracted, use:

```
sed -n 's/.*--test=.*\s\+\(\S\+\)\s*$/\1/p' file
```